# Submitting ios6 app from XCode 4.x

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently there is Xcode 5.The question is, can i submit my app witch supports iOS 6.1 ,through Xcode 4.x version ?

**NOTE:** I have no installed Xcode 5 because of my osx 10.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, Apple will ask you to include a 120x120 icon for iOS 7 devices both they will accept your app submission.

I've been sumbit some app with Xcode 4.6 which I installed next to Xcode 5.